# Return data into a table

Tags: jquery

ok i'm new to jquery and ajax i have this code and it works but i want the data to be returned in a table format

---------------------------------------------------------------jsfile----------------------

```
   $('input#data-submit').on('click',function(){
     var data=$('input#data').val();
      var data2=$('select#data2').val();

      if(data2=="Name")
      {
          if($.trim(data)!=''){
              $.post('Ajax/dataloader.php',{data:data},function(data){
                $('div#load').text(data)
              });
          }
      }
      else if(data2=="Location")
      {
        if($.trim(data)!=''){
              $.post('Ajax/dataloader2.php',{data:data},function(data){
                $('div#load').text(data)
              });
          }
      }

});
```

### -----------------------------------------------from-----------------------------------------

```
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <h1>P-CAT version 0.1</h1>
</div>



    <div id ="content">
     <h2>Sreach  Catigroies</h2>
     <select id="data2">
     <option value="">Plece select one of the follwing</option>
      <option value="Name">Name</option>
      <option value="Location">Location</option>
    </select>
    <input name="data" id="data" type="text" />
    <input type="submit"  id="data-submit" value="Grab">



        <div id="load">    
        </div>
        </div>


    <div id="navbar">
        <input type="button" value="EDIT">
        <input type="button" value="HISTORY">
        <input type="button" value="SETTINGS">
        <input type="button" value="SEARCH">
    </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your framework doesn't have the ability to create tables, you can search on your favorite search engine for "jquery table"

Here is one example of a plugin that's simple to use: https://datatables.net/

Check it out at let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thanks but i want to know if/how i can edit my current js file to return the values in a table format

Comment: If you want to show the data in a table format on the page without use a table framework, you'll have to create the table html dynamically.  Is that what you're asking for?  Let me know!

Comment: I would still recommend using a table plugin like I said in my answer though.  Table plugins give you a little more flexibility for example if you wanted to add more usability and styling to your table... like sorting, editing, paging, etc...